# Import CSV using LOAD DATA getting wrong values

Tags: mysql

I have a big csv (near 100mb) that I would like to import in a table with the following structure:

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cep         | varchar(255)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| site        | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cidade      | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uf          | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cepbase     | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| segmentacao | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| area        | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cepstatus   | int(1)           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| score       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fila        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I was about to write some code to import but I've found a MySQL command that does the job to me. So I've write the following:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/user/Downloads/base.csv'
INTO TABLE cep_status_new
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@id,@cep,@site,@cidade,@uf,@cepbase,@segmentacao,@area,@cepstatus,@score,@fila)
SET id=NULL, cep=@col1, site='GOD', cidade=@col6, uf=@col7, cepbase='-', segmentacao=@col9, cepstatus=@col2, area='BING', score=99999, fila=5;
```

To try this code, I've removed thousand lines from my CSV and let only 2 lines: header and an input example:

```
cep,status,gang,bang,random,mock,awesome,qwert,hero
01019000,0,00387,00388,3550308,SAO PAULO,SP,011,B2
```

The code runs without problem but my insert is pretty strange:

```
mysql> select * from cep_status_new;
+----+------+------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-----------+-------+------+
| id | cep  | site | cidade | uf      | cepbase | segmentacao | area | cepstatus | score | fila |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-----------+-------+------+
|  1 | 1    | GOD  | 24655  | 3554805 | -       | SP          | BING |         0 | 99999 |    5 |
+----+------+------+--------+---------+---------+-------------+------+-----------+-------+------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Why values from CSV are not being filled correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [specification](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) the column list after `IGNORE 1 ROWS` decides how the columns of the CSV file are mapped to columns of the table. It can either list the table columns in the order of the file or it can load the file columns into variables. With the column list

`(@id,@cep,@site,@cidade,@uf,@cepbase,@segmentacao,@area,@cepstatus,@score,@fila)`

you are loading 11 columns of the CSV file into variables named "id", "cep", etc. In the `SET` statement you then need to declare how the columns of the table are constructed from the variables. With the given statement you are refering to variables `@col1` etc. that are not defined anywhere and consequently have undefined values.

The corrected statement (that I sadly can't test myself right now) should be:

```
INTO TABLE cep_status_new
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@col1,@col2,@col3,@col4,@col5,@col6,@col7,@col8,@col9)
SET id=NULL, cep=@col1, site='GOD', cidade=@col6, uf=@col7, cepbase='-', segmentacao=@col9, cepstatus=@col2, area='BING', score=99999, fila=5;
```